# R: switch statement with multiple lines

Tags: r, switch-statement

In R: I have a matrix with one column classified by 8 types: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h. I need to do different computations for each type using the data in the other columns. I want to use a switch() function to automate the looping through each type and state the difference calculations for each type; HOWEVER, everything I am seeing online only shows examples of the syntax for one line switch computations for each switch.

Here is an example using the code provided in the switch() help. I know that mean() is a function, but let's just say for this example, that it isn't a function, because I just want to illustrate that I do not know the syntax (and it's not clearly stated in my research online):

```
centre <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
     mean = {
           total.sum<-sum(type)
           mean = total.sum/length(type)
     },
     median = median(x),
     trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
}
```

Comment: There's a number of ways to do this. Maybe if you expanded your question, preferably with a reproducible example we might be of more help.

Comment: This will be much more likely to be answered if you provide something reproducible and your efforts toward a solution.

Comment: Just use braces `{...}` to wrap your multiple lines of code for each statement

Comment: While I agree that more detail in the question would remove ambiguity, @Andrie 's comment is sufficient for the question posed.

Comment: please see revised question for sample code to illustrate my confusion.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and try that code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the miscommunication is coming from a typo in your example:

```
 mean = {
       total.sum<-sum(type)
       mean = total.sum/length(type)
 },
```

should be

```
 mean = {
       total.sum<-sum(x)
       mean = total.sum/length(x)
 },
```

If you make this change, it behaves exactly how you would expect it to.

ETA: I'm not sure what the issue is in your comment. Please try the following code:

```
set.seed(1)

centre <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
     mean = {
           total.sum<-sum(x)
           mean = total.sum/length(x)
     },
     median = median(x),
     trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
}

x <- rcauchy(10)
print(centre(x, "mean"))
print(centre(x, "median"))
print(centre(x, "trimmed"))
```

The output is:

```
[1] -0.4844658
[1] -0.236111
[1] -0.3632328
```

Comment: Well the syntax still has to be wrong because when I run the code with this correction, and then use the fucntion, I get the following: 'x <- rcauchy(10)
> centre(x, "mean")
> centre(x, "median")
[1] 0.3268971
> centre(x, "trimmed")
[1] 1.677625'

Comment: See edit for a reproducible example; and let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: For some reason when I made the correction (which I tried to show by embedding code, and the site wouldn't let me hit enter without submitting it). The problem I was having was that it wasn't producing a result. Since you showed me yours, and I ran it, the problem seems to be resolved. THANKS!